# Dependency Injection unable to resolve service for type in .NET Core Function App running in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, azure-functions

### Summary

I've been following the Microsoft guidance [Use dependency injection in .NET Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection) to introduce some Dependency Injection (DI) into an Azure Function that our team is creating. When I run locally in Visual Studio 2017 and invoke the function using Fiddler or Postman everything works - I can debug hitting breakpoints and the service being provided via the DI setup are working correctly. When we deploy the same function into Azure, however, we get the following exception:

> **Unable to resolve service for type 'MyLibrary.ITelemetryClient' while
>   attempting to activate 'MyFunctionApp.GetRemoteSystemsByFeature'.**

### Details

I have a library assembly (.NET Standard 2.0) that exposes an interface, `ITelemetryClient`, and a default implementation, `ApplicationInsightsTelemetryClient`. They're pretty straightforward bits of code - I don't think the implementation of *these* are important to the issue, so I'll skip them for now.

In the solution that defines our function app (.NET Core 2.2) I've made sure the right NuGet packages are installed:

- Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions v1.0.0
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator v1.1.1
- Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions v1.0.28

I have created `Startup` which inherits from `FunctionsStartup`:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using MyLibrary;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyFunctionApp.Startup))]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyFunctionApp.Tests")]

namespace MyFunctionApp
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<MyLibrary.ITelemetryClient, MyLibrary.ApplicationInsightsTelemetryClient>();
        }
    }
}
```

I then give my function a constructor that asks for the `MyLibrary.ITelemetryClient`:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MyLibrary;
using MyRepository;
using MyService;

namespace MyFunctionApp
{
    public class GetRemoteSystemsByFeature
    {
        private readonly MyLibrary.ITelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

        public GetRemoteSystemsByFeature(MyLibrary.ITelemetryClient telemetryClient)
        {
            _telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
        }

        // snip - the rest shouldn't matter for this question
    }
}
```

So I *think* I've done everything right. And as I said when I debug locally the whole thing works and the correct `ITelemetryClient` implementation is used and successfully does its thing.

When it gets deployed into Azure, though, we get the error quoted above. The stack trace for that exception doesn't mention any of our code:

```
System.InvalidOperationException:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at lambda_method (Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultJobActivator.CreateInstance (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\DefaultJobActivator.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 42)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultJobActivator.CreateInstance (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\DefaultJobActivator.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 32)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ActivatorInstanceFactory`1+<>c__DisplayClass1_1.<.ctor>b__0 (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\ActivatorInstanceFactory.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 20)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ActivatorInstanceFactory`1.Create (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\ActivatorInstanceFactory.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 26)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.CreateInstance (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 44)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+ParameterHelper.Initialize (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 845)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryExecuteAsyncCore>d__16.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 116)
```

Any ideas?

### Update

It was requested I share the contents of the `extensions.json` file:

```json
{
  "extensions":[
    { "name": "Startup", "typeName":"MyFunctionApp.Startup, MyFunctionApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Looks fine on the face of it, I've deployed an Azure function that uses DI in the last few days that doesn't do anything extra, worth checking the dependencies of your concrete class but looks like you've already tried this with your "Null" implementation. It may be worth digging around in your function's storage because you get all the logging stored in table storage there, this may give some extra clues.

Comment: Im struggling with the same, trying some ideas in here which talks about changing the Runtime: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4187

Comment: BigPigVT, what version of the runtime are you using when you run locally, and what version of the runtime is your function app on Azure set to?

Comment: Jamie, thank you for the link. I tried changing the `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` in Azure to 2.0.12342.0, which one commenter cited as working, and unfortunately the issue still occurred.

Comment: Katy, in Azure the `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` is `~2` (though we've also tried 2.0.12342.0). When I run locally it is 2.0.12507.0.

Comment: Thanks, BigPigVT. Your code looks fine, though I'd recommend removing the ExtensionsMetadataGenerator reference. Can you share the contents of your `extensions.csproj` file (located in `/bin`)?

Comment: Katy, I've appended the contents of the `extensions.json` file to my original post. I'll try removing the ExtensionsMetadataGenerator reference.

Comment: Katy, my initial report back that removing the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator` package didn't do anything was wrong... I had forgotten to uncomment the registration in my `Startup` class. 

Dependency injection is now working correctly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After uninstalling the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator` package from the `MyFunctionApp` and redeploying the dependency injection errors stopped and things started working correctly. Thanks to anyone who offered their insights, especially to [Katy Shimizu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8896339/katy-shimizu).

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was missing
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyFunctionApp.Startup))]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` to your project and add this to your `Startup.cs` class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Joey. I don't think the issue has to do with how Application Insights is, or isn't, configured, though. The `ITelemetryClient` my `Startup` class is registering is a `MyLibrary.ITelemetryClient` to be fulfilled by a `MyLibrary.ApplicationInsightsTelemetryClient`. I believe if I change the service so that `MyLibrary.ITelemetryClient` is fulfilled by a `MyLibrary.NullTelemetryClient` (which implements the interface but doesn't do anything) I will get the same result. I'm testing that now. But I think the issue is with the dependency injection itself.

Comment: I confirmed that changing the service to be a MyLibrary.NullTelemetryClient results in the same error: System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to resolve service for type 'MyLibrary.ITelemetryClient' while attempting to activate 'MyFunctionApp.GetRemoteSystemsByFeature' So I don't think the issue has to do with how Application Insights is configured because in the MyLibrary.NullTelemetryClient we're not dependent on it. Let me know if I'm missing an aspect of this, though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a lot of messing about, i just updated my Microsoft.NET.sdk.Functions to 1.0.28 and im now getting an application error so its got past the DI error. Try that and let me know how you get on.

Ok i see you are on 1.0.28, im using .netcore 2.1 if that helps?

Comment: Jamie, what happens if you go from .NET Core 2.1 to .NET Core 2.2 (which is what our function is on)? I'd prefer to not downgrade if possible.

Comment: @BigPigVT I dont have 2.2 installed on this machine. Have you tried injecting as AddScoped? FYI im using runtime version 2.0.12507.0 with Sdk 1.0.28. I was also totally removing the functions from Azure each time i tried a new approach (To make sure no orphaned files were left over) One last thing im doing differently is adding builder.Services.AddHttpClient(); before any injections.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this exact problem, trying to deploy an Azure Function CosmosDB ChangeFeedListener. Locally ran fine, once deployed it couldn't find the dependencies to inject in Startup.

There is a long history of DI issues with Azure Functions. Went down a long rabbit hole for this one.

**Problem**:
`/publish/bin/extensions.json` was being generated like this:

```
{
   "extensions":
    [
     { "name": "CosmosDB", 
       "typeName":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB.CosmosDBWebJobsStartup, 
        Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB, Version=3.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, 
        PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
     }
   ]
}
```

Instead of this:

```
{
   "extensions":
    [
     { "name": "Startup", "typeName":"<ProjectNamespace>.Startup, <ProjectNamespace>, 
        Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"},
     { "name": "CosmosDB", 
       "typeName":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB.CosmosDBWebJobsStartup, 
        Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB, Version=3.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, 
        PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
     }
   ]
}
```

**Solution**:

```
Remove Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions
```

Azure Function .csproj:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
```